# Proof of trigonometric identity $\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B + \cos A\sin B$

Tags: trigonometry

All the proofs I've seen are geometrical, assuming that $A+B$ is less than $90$ degrees. How can you prove this identity for $A+B$ greater than $90$ degrees, or more generally, any arbitrary value?

Comment: I'm sure you can just modify the usual arguments, even if the sum _is_ greater than 90 - you'll just have to be careful with the signed lengths.

Comment: Easiest way, though, would probably be to mess with coordinates and the unit circle.

Comment: See [this recent answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/911101/155509).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want a geometrical proof, then you need to indicate how you are defining $\cos$ and $\sin$. One way to define them is that $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ are the real and imaginary parts of $\exp(ix)$, and use the property that
$$\exp(i(a+b)) = \exp(ia)\exp(ib)$$
Then 
$$\begin{align}
\exp(i(a+b))
&= \exp(ia)\exp(ib)\\
&=  (\cos(a) + i\sin(a))(\cos(b) + i\sin(b))\\
&= \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b) + i(\sin(a)\cos(b) + \cos(a)\sin(b)) \\
\end{align}$$
And from this we obtain two trig identities at once:
$$\cos(a+b) = \text{Re}(\exp(i(a+b))) = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b)$$
$$\sin(a+b) = \text{Im}(\exp(i(a+b))) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \cos(a)\sin(b)$$

Comment: But that requires knowing the Taylor series of sine, which requires knowing the derivative of sine... which involves knowing the summation formula. Besides, I think that this is much more heavy machinery than needed. I'm guessing that the OP wants a proof that is geometrical, but isn't restricted to $0\le\theta<90^\circ$.

Comment: May be you could remove the reference to the power series that, in any manner, you don't use in your good answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici But how else do you prove that sine and cosine are the real and imaginary parts of $\exp(ix)$? I know know way that doesn't involve differentiating the trig functions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I just realized - you don't need to prove that $\exp(ix)$ is anything. You only need to prove De Moivre - that $\arg(wz)=\arg(w)+\arg(z)$. This can be done more easily, by noting that rotation is linear.

Comment: I am glad to see that we totally agree ! Cheers :-)

Comment: I'm lost. I've not done the Taylor series yet.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Suppose that the two unit circles in the diagram are centered at the origin, with the second one rotated clockwise by $\measuredangle A$. Note that the two red line have equal length. Find the coordinates of $P,Q,R,\text{ and } S$ (but especially $Q$). Use this information to derive $\sin(A+B)$ and $\cos(A+B)$.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Very elegant.

Comment: I can't find the method. Could you please explain?

Comment: point $P$ has coordinates $(\cos A, \sin A)$. What are $Q,R,$ and $S$'s coordinates?

Comment: Clean and awesome!